# How to route Nexmo notification from different field Laravel?

Tags: laravel, notifications, sms, vonage

I am trying to route my Nexmo notification in Laravel from a field other than `phone_number` which is what the docs state Nexmo looks for to use. I added this snippet of code from the Laravel docs:

```
public function routeNotificationForNexmo($notification)
{
    return $this->phone;
}
```

Because the field in my db is `phone`. But, when this is run, I get an error that says `Type error: Too few arguments to function App\User::routeNotificationForNexmo()`. What I don't understand is where I would pass through any data to this, and the Laravel docs don't state anymore about custom routing. So how do I route a Nexmo notification from a field other than `phone_number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove the argument inside the `routeNotificationForNexmo()` function :

```
public function routeNotificationForNexmo()
{
    return $this->phone;
}
```

Comment: I had tried that before but was getting a different error, turns out it was due to the format of phone number, not the removing of the argument.